# Replace missing html_nodes while using rvest in R

Tags: html, r, html-parsing, rvest

I am trying to parse an html   which has a few li elements inside them.This is just a sample html I have kept with two divs. I have almost 7000 divs to be parsed. Not all of the divs have all the `li` elements in them.For eg. `<li class="brewery_type">` might be not available in all divs. Due to that this code wont be able to populate all the values into the tibble. In that case how can I still parse through this and replace the missing li elements in that div with NA.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

html_file <- '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="brewery" id="brewery">
        <ul class="vcard simple">
            <li class="name"> Bradley Farm / RB Brew, LLC</li>
            <li class="address">317 Springtown Rd </li>
            <li class="address_2">New Paltz, NY 12561-3020 | <a href="http://www.google.com/maps/place/317 Springtown Rd++New Paltz+NY+United States" target="_blank">Map</a> </li>
            <li class="telephone">Phone: (845) 255-8769</li>
            <li class="brewery_type">Type: Micro</li>
            <li class="url"><a href="http://www.raybradleyfarm.com" target="_blank">www.raybradleyfarm.com</a> </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="vcard simple col2"></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="brewery">
        <ul class="vcard simple">
            <li class="name">(405) Brewing Co</li>
            <li class="address">1716 Topeka St </li>
            <li class="address_2">Norman, OK 73069-8224 | <a href="http://www.google.com/maps/place/1716 Topeka St++Norman+OK+United States" target="_blank">Map</a> </li>
            <li class="telephone">Phone: (405) 816-0490</li>
            <li class="brewery_type">Type: Micro</li>
            <li class="url"><a href="http://www.405brewing.com" target="_blank">www.405brewing.com</a> </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="vcard simple col2"></ul>
    </div>
</body>'

page <- read_html(html_file) 

tibble(
  name = page %>% html_nodes(".vcard .name") %>% html_text(),
  address = page %>% html_nodes(".vcard .address") %>% html_text(),
  type = page %>% html_nodes(".vcard .brewery_type") %>% html_text() %>% stringr::str_replace_all("^Type: ", ""),
  website = page %>% html_nodes(".vcard .url a") %>% html_attr("href")
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of parsing all of the tags in one pass, I parsed out the div.brewery into a list of elements/nodes and then extracted the requested information from each brewery individually.  Not as efficient but it tracks the relevant information to each parent.  This model is assuming only one child element per parent.  Thus only one name, address, website per div.brewery

```
library(rvest)

html_file <- '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="brewery" id="brewery">
<ul class="vcard simple">
<li class="name"> Bradley Farm / RB Brew, LLC</li>
<li class="address">317 Springtown Rd </li>
<li class="address_2">New Paltz, NY 12561-3020 | <a href="http://www.google.com/maps/place/317 Springtown Rd++New Paltz+NY+United States" target="_blank">Map</a> </li>
<li class="telephone">Phone: (845) 255-8769</li>
<li class="brewery_type">Type: Micro</li>
<li class="url"><a href="http://www.raybradleyfarm.com" target="_blank">www.raybradleyfarm.com</a> </li>
</ul>
<ul class="vcard simple col2"></ul>
</div>
<div class="brewery">
<ul class="vcard simple">
<li class="name">(405) Brewing Co</li>
<li class="address">1716 Topeka St </li>
<li class="address_2">Norman, OK 73069-8224 | <a href="http://www.google.com/maps/place/1716 Topeka St++Norman+OK+United States" target="_blank">Map</a> </li>
<li class="telephone">Phone: (405) 816-0490</li>

<li class="url"><a href="http://www.405brewing.com" target="_blank">www.405brewing.com</a> </li>
</ul>
<ul class="vcard simple col2"></ul>
</div>
</body>'

page <- read_html(html_file) 

breweries<-page %>% html_nodes("div.brewery")

name<- breweries %>% html_node(".vcard .name") %>% html_text()
address<- breweries %>% html_node(".vcard .address") %>% html_text()
type<- breweries %>% html_node(".vcard .brewery_type") %>% html_text()
type<-gsub("^Type: ", "", type)
website<- breweries %>% html_node(".vcard .url a") %>% html_text()

tibble(name, address, type, website)
```